# Chrome Extension : changing iframe source content after injected to a given page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have started to write a chrome extension, what I'm trying to do is the following:
1) detect new tab load, and on complete load do (2)
2) inject an iframe into the loaded page
3) change the iframe's src inner HTML.

my manifest is: (at this moment i am not using the localhost permission)

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "My extension",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "description" : "Extensioning",
    "background" : {
        "page" : "background.html"
        },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs","https://*/*","http://*/*","http://localhost/*"],
    "web_accessible_resources" : ["background.js","content_script.js","MainExtension.html","MainExtension.css","MainExtension.js","jquery-1.11.1.min.js"]
}
```

my background.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

my background.js(detecting loaded tab and injecting the script into the page)

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab)
{
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete")
    {
        alert("good");
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{ file : "content_script.js"});
    }

});
```

my content_script.js :(adding element 'injected_frame' with src "MainExtension.html")

```
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.id = "injected_frame";
f.style.zIndex = "2147483647";
f.style.top = "10%";
f.style.left = "0px";
f.style.position = "fixed";
f.style.width = "320px";
f.style.height = "240px";
f.style.border = "0px";
f.style.margin = "0px";
f.style.padding  = "0px";
f.src = chrome.extension.getURL('MainExtension.html');
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

MainExtension.html(showed in the iframe):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="MainExtension.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="MainExtension.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "headersection">
        <p id = "imgwrapper">
            <img src ="mystock.png" alt = "My E" id = "logoimg">
        </p>
        <p id = "headertext">My Extension</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id = "infosection">
        <p> p found : bla1,bla2,</p>
        <p> a : s1 </p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "datas">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is :
after I added the iframe in the injected script(content_script.js), I want to change the MainExtention.html which is the src of the 'injected_frame' element.

How can I do that or can you suggest any alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the code above currently working, ie does the iframe get created correctly? Also, under what conditions do you want the iframe html to change? User clicks something? Specific websites?

Comment: Yes, the iframe is created correctly. I want the iframe html to change after my background.js script requests a remote server for data, and then i want to show it in the iframe html(The request is not the problem here).

Answer (score 0):

I would try one of two things:

1) Make the data request to the server from the content script directly (recommended).

2) Send the HTML via message passing:

Modify `content_script.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(html) {
  if (html) {
    f.innerHTML = html;
  }
});
```

And modify `background.js` to include something like the following:

```
function onReceiveFromServer(html) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, html);
}
```

Comment: I didn't check it yet, but my content_script isn't realy a content_script, it is an injected script, from the documentation i understood that I can't use chrome API's there, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think it's still considered a content script. You can't use some things like chrome.tabs but chrome.runtime should work with the proper permissions.

Comment: Hey. I used your suggestion to make the data request to the server from the content script(works perfect) . in my background.js i got now :chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab)
{
 if(changeInfo.status == "complete")
 {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {url: ""+tab.url}, function(response) {
    alert(response.farewell);
    });
  });
 }
}); here i send message to the injected script

Comment: and in the injected_script.js i got :chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var content = "";
 var mainurl = //my server
 $.get(mainurl,function(data)
 {
  content = data;
  if(content.trim() != ""){
   AddFrame();
  }
 });
 }); here im getting the message and requesting to the server. the problem is i can't send the response back to the background, if i put it inside the $.get , it doesn't send any response back...